# PyLTSpice "LTSpice_Batch" function not working

Tags: python

I'm using VSCode with Python 3.11.0 in a virtual enviroment. I have installed the aforementioned toolchain to configure and launch LTSpice models.

However, it seems not to work and I cannot find why (I'm quite new to python programming). I attach here the actual code and the traceback. Notice that the main code is taken from the example given in its webpage.

The code:

```
import os
from PyLTSpice.LTSpiceBatch import SimCommander

# get script absolute path
meAbsPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("Draft1.asc"))
meAbsPath = meAbsPath + '/Draft1.asc'
print(str(meAbsPath))


# select spice model
LTC = SimCommander(meAbsPath)

# set default arguments
# LTC.set_parameters(res=0, cap=100e-6)
LTC.set_component_value('R1', '2k')
LTC.set_component_value('L1', '1u')
# LTC.set_element_model('V3', "SINE(0 1 3k 0 0 0)")
# define simulation
LTC.add_instructions(
    "; Simulation settings",
    ".param run = 0"
)

LTC.reset_netlist()
LTC.add_instructions(
    "; Simulation settings",
    ".tran 0 10u 0 1n",
)

LTC.run()
LTC.wait_completion()

# Sim Statistics
print('Successful/Total Simulations: ' + str(LTC.okSim) + '/' + str(LTC.runno))
```

The traceback log:

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\ciko9\Documents\VSCode_Projects\.venv>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\ciko9\Documents\VSCode_Projects\.venv'; & 'c:\Users\ciko9\Documents\VSCode_Projects\.venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'c:\Users\ciko9\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '51647' '--' 'c:\Users\ciko9\Documents\VSCode_Projects\.venv\lts_run.py' 
C:\Users\ciko9\Documents\VSCode_Projects\.venv/Draft1.asc
Creating Netlist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ciko9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ciko9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\ciko9\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\ciko9\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\ciko9\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\ciko9\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\ciko9\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\ciko9\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\ciko9\Documents\VSCode_Projects\.venv\lts_run.py", line 11, in <module>
    LTC = SimCommander(meAbsPath)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\ciko9\Documents\VSCode_Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\PyLTSpice\LTSpiceBatch.py", line 288, in __init__
    retcode = run_function(cmd_netlist)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\ciko9\Documents\VSCode_Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\PyLTSpice\LTSpiceBatch.py", line 136, in run_function
    result = subprocess.run(command, timeout=timeout)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ciko9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 546, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ciko9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1022, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\ciko9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1491, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\ciko9\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 853, in new_CreateProcess
    return getattr(_subprocess, original_name)(app_name, cmd_line, *args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```

I guess that it actually finds the ".asc" LTSpice model file, but at some point it misses something but I could not figure out what is it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The cause is now understood.
pyLTSpiceBatch.py is referring the XVIIx64.exe path directly.

```
else:  # Windows
    LTspice_exe = [r"C:\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceXVII\XVIIx64.exe"]
    LTspice_arg = {'netlist': ['-netlist'], 'run': ['-b', '-Run']}
    PROCNAME = "XVIIx64.exe"
```

If you installed LTSpice to except above path, SimCommander is not work.
Then you need action either one,

1. Replace the installed LTSpice to default path C:\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceXVII.
2. Rewrite LTSpice path in pyLTSpiceBatch.py

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem too yesterday.
By any chance, were you trying it on windows 11?
If that, it is same as my situation. Probably it will work on windows 10.
I do not know why though, it seems like that subprocess.py or command prompt is not work normally on windows 11.
Hoping that the information will be of some help to you.